# App failing to start because migration was not applied

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-7.0, ef-core-7.0

I've been using Entity Framework Core for months without issue, but today I started getting an error when I tried to deploy the latest version of my app:

> HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start

From the information I can see, it appears that the app appears to be starting before the migration is applied, or that the migration isn't being applied.  For some reason EF Core is not able to add/view/utilise my new column. Here's what I've found so far...

The migration is very basic; just adding a new column to the Users table:

[image]

Within the database I list all rows within the migrations table and see this, which shows that the new migration isn't being applied:

[image].

I enabled Application Insights to try and get some exception details and see this (`Invalid column name 'AccountApproved'`):

```
An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'MyData.MyContext'.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'AccountApproved'.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__208_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__273_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
Error Number:207,State:1,Class:16
ClientConnectionId before routing:5a55dab2-5b31-4ffd-bfeb-0ae290f6d036
Routing Destination:f87bbce0831f.tr5515.uksouth1-a.worker.database.windows.net,11011
```

I don't understand why this isn't working all of a sudden, especially when the migration is so simple.  Can anyone please advise how I can get the migration to apply?  I assume I can manually add the column via TSQL and then fudge the migration table to add the latest migration, but I'm nervous about making the issue worse when that might not be a good approach.

### Update (24 hours of trial and error...)

After trying pretty much everything I could think of, due to pressure I had to use Azure database query editor console to create the column manually and insert the MigrationId to match the Migrations folder in the project.  The web app now works as expected but I would still appreciate understanding why the migration script wasn't applied on publish?

Comment: EF Core migrations are not applied automatically. You must manually invoke `Update-Database` command (or its CLI equivalent), or somewhere inside your app startup obtain the `DbContext` and call `context.Database.Migrate()`.  See [Applying migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) topic in the EF Core docs.

Comment: This is only occurring on the live (prod) database.  The local one runs fine.  I've never had to manually apply `Update-Database` as it usually does this during the publish operation.  Although as of today it isn't